A simple pivot_longer on 3D array in R?
Given the array foo, how can I make a data.frame bar using pivot_longer? I have a 2-step solution using pivot_longer followed by separate_wider_delim but I can I accomplish this all in pivot_longer using the names_sep  argument?
# what I have
foo <- array(1:24,dim = c(4,3,2))
dimnames(foo) <- list(NULL,paste0("varName",1:3),paste0("Iteration",1:2))

foo

#what I want
bar <- data.frame(value=1:24,
                  varName = rep(c("y1","y2","y3"),each=4),
                  Iteration = c(rep("z1",times=12),rep("z2",times=12)))
bar

# A 2-step solution
bar2 <- as.data.frame(foo) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  separate_wider_delim(cols=name, delim=".", names=c("varName","Iteration"))

bar2


Added some name repair to get your "y"s and "z"s and also selected and arranged to match desired output. Note, names_sep is a regexp so must escape the dot.
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

foo <- array(1:24,dim = c(4,3,2))
dimnames(foo) <- list(NULL,paste0("varName",1:3),paste0("Iteration",1:2))

foo %>% 
  as_tibble(
    .name_repair = ~ str_replace_all(., c("varName" = "y", "Iteration" = "z"))
  ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    everything(), 
    names_to = c("varName", "Iteration"), 
    names_sep = "\\."
  ) %>% 
  select(value, varName, Iteration) %>%
  arrange(value, varName, Iteration)
#> # A tibble: 24 × 3
#>    value varName Iteration
#>    <int> <chr>   <chr>    
#>  1     1 y1      z1       
#>  2     2 y1      z1       
#>  3     3 y1      z1       
#>  4     4 y1      z1       
#>  5     5 y2      z1       
#>  6     6 y2      z1       
#>  7     7 y2      z1       
#>  8     8 y2      z1       
#>  9     9 y3      z1       
#> 10    10 y3      z1       
#> # ℹ 14 more rows

Created on 2024-04-09 with reprex v2.1.0

Actually, as.data.frame.table basically gives you what you want.
> as.data.frame.table(foo, responseName="value")[c(4, 2, 3)] |> head(3)
  value     Var2       Var3
1     1 varName1 Iteration1
2     2 varName1 Iteration1
3     3 varName1 Iteration1
4   ...

Just use in combination with some string handling.
> dn <- dimnames(foo)[-1] |> sapply(el) |> sub('\\d+$', '', x=_)
> res <- as.data.frame.table(foo, responseName="value")[c(4, 2, 3)]
> names(res)[-1] <- dn
> res[2:3] <- lapply(res[2:3], stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed, vectorize_all=FALSE,
+                    pattern=c(dn[1], dn[2]), replacement=c('y', 'z'))
> res
   value varName Iteration
1      1      y1        z1
2      2      y1        z1
3      3      y1        z1
4      4      y1        z1
5      5      y2        z1
6      6      y2        z1
7      7      y2        z1
8      8      y2        z1
9      9      y3        z1
10    10      y3        z1
11    11      y3        z1
12    12      y3        z1
13    13      y1        z2
14    14      y1        z2
15    15      y1        z2
16    16      y1        z2
17    17      y2        z2
18    18      y2        z2
19    19      y2        z2
20    20      y2        z2
21    21      y3        z2
22    22      y3        z2
23    23      y3        z2
24    24      y3        z2
> stopifnot(all.equal(bar, res))

Note, that there's probably some misunderstanding of what an R-"array" is -- a vector with dimensions attribute. We can get the "value" column simply by removing the dimensions, i.e. `dim<-`(foo, NULL), or simply
> as.vector(foo)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24

Reshaping stuff (wide-to-long etc.) isn't necessary, which would also be very inefficient.
